# Seleccionar varios días en Calendar WPF sin pulsar Ctrl

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

Estoy usando un objeto Calendar en una aplicación WPF. Mi objetivo es que el usuario pueda seleccionar o deseleccionar tantos días como quiera. Para ello, he puesto la etiqueta SelectionMode="MultipleRange", sin embargo, es necesario mantener pulsada la tecla Ctrl para seleccionar varios días. Además, si se selecciona algún día sin tener Ctrl pulsada, se deseleccionan todos los dias seleccionados anteriormente.
¿Alguien sabe si existe algun modo de poder seleccionar días sin necesidad de pulsar la tecla Ctrl?
O, en su defecto, ¿alguien sabe como "simular" el pulsar y mantener una tecla pulsada en WPF?

Muchas gracias!! Un Saludo!

Comment: si es un rango de fechas, porqué no usar dos calendar? uno de fecha inicio, y uno de fecha fin

Comment: Se me ocurre que al seleccionar una fecha la agregues a una lista y luego abras el calendario por código nuevamente para seleccionar otra fecha y así hasta que tengas todas las que quieras, y luego con la tecla ESC o pulsando fuera lo cierras...